# Extract new feature from sentence column - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have two dataframes:

`city_state` dataframe

```
    city        state
0   huntsville  alabama
1   montgomery  alabama
2   birmingham  alabama
3   mobile      alabama
4   dothan      alabama
5   chicago     illinois
6   boise       idaho
7   des moines  iowa
```

and sentence dataframe

```
    sentence
0   marthy was born in dothan
1   michelle reads some books at her home
2   hasan is highschool student in chicago
3   hartford of the west is the nickname of des moines
```

I want to extract new feature from sentence dataframe called city. That column `city` is extracted from `sentence` if in the sentence contain a name of certain `city` from column `city_state['city']`, if it didn't contain a name of certain `city` its value will be Null.

The expected new dataframe will be like this:

```
    sentence                                        city
0   marthy was born in dothan                       dothan
1   michelle reads some books at her home           Null
2   hasan is highschool student in chicago          chicago
3   capital of dream is the motto of des moines     des moines
```

I have run this code

```
sentence['city'] ={}

for city in city_state.city:
    for text in sentence.sentence:
        words = text.split()
        for word in words:
            if word == city:
                sentence['city'].append(city)
                break
    else:
        sentence['city'].append(None)
```

but the result of this code is like this

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

If you have experience on feature engineering with similar case, could you give me some suggestion how to write the right code for expected result.

Thank you

Note:
This is the full log of the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-205-8a9038a015ee> in <module>
----> 1 sentence['city'] ={}
      2 
      3 for city in city_state.city:
      4     for text in sentence.sentence:
      5         words = text.split()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3117         else:
   3118             # set column
-> 3119             self._set_item(key, value)
   3120 
   3121     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3192 
   3193         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3194         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3195         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3196 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3389 
   3390             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3391             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3392             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3393                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
   3999 
   4000     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 4001         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
   4002 
   4003     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: Instead of using `apply`, you can use `str.findall` by `df["found"] = df["sentence"].str.findall("|".join(city_state["city"])).str[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick and dirty apply, haven't tested it on large dataframes so use it with caution.
First define a function to extract city names:

```py
def ex_city(col, cities):
    output = []
    for w in cities:
        if w in col:
            output.append(w)
    return ','.join(output) if output else None
```

Then apply it to your sentence dataframe

```py
city_list = city_state.city.unique().tolist()
sentence['city'] = sentence['sentence'].apply(lambda x: ex_city(x, city_list))
```

Comment: Thanks you @atl , I have implemented your code and it works for a single word city, but it didn't work for two-words city like des moines. For the two-words city, the extraction is NaN. Maybe it because the sentence is splitted to single word
```
 sentence         city
0 marthy was born in dothan     dothan
1 michelle reads some books at her home  NaN
2 hasan is highschool student in chicago   chicago
3 capital of dream is the motto of des moines  NaN
```

Comment: Edited one more time, I tested on a sentence dataframe with 2 million rows and it took about 1.6s to execute

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work. I'd try it myself but I'm on my phone.

```
sentence_cities =[]
cities = city_state.city

for text in sentence.sentence:
    [sentence_cities.append(word) if word in cities else sentence_cities.append(None) for word in text.split()]

sentence['city'] = sentence_cities
```

Answer (score 0):

let `sdf = sentence dataframe` and `cdf=city_state dataframe`

`des moines` will be an issue when doing `str.split` since it has a space in the name.

First (or last, testing needed) get that city

`sdf.loc[sdf['sentence'].str.contains('des moines'), 'city'] = 'des moines'`

Then the rest

```
def get_city(sentence, cities):
    for word in sentence.split(' '):
        if sentence in cities:
           return word
    return None

cities = cdf['city'].tolist()
sdf['city'] = sdf['sentence'].apply(lambda x: get_city(x, cities))
```